# Send POST data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, image-uploading

I am uploading files, in such a way the user does not need to hit the button 'Upload' after selecting the file. It works fine but I also need to send an extra parameter and, since I'm not into Javascript at all, I can not figure out how to send it. 
The html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_blank" name="send_img" id="send_img" method="post" action="img_upload.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="group_id" name="group_id" value="2" />
    <input type="file" class="hide" id="uploaded_file" name="uploaded_file" onChange="Handlechange();"/>
    <button type="submit" id="btn">Subir fotos!</button>
</form>

<div onclick="HandleBrowseClick();" id="fakeBrowse" >Load a picture</div>
```

The script:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function HandleBrowseClick()
{
    var fileinput = document.getElementById("uploaded_file");
    fileinput.click();
}

function Handlechange()
{
    var fileinput = document.getElementById("uploaded_file");
    var textinput = document.getElementById("filename");
    textinput.value = fileinput.value;
}
</script>
```

I have no clue how to send the group_id variable (which I have in a php variable, so it can be echoed anywhere, even in the script). I tried many ways with no luck. So how can that variable to be passed and gotten in img_upload.php?
I thought that:

`var group_id = document.getElementById("group_id").value;`

would make it but I was wrong :-/

What I also find interesting is that if I modify the form tag to `action="img_upload.php?group_id=2"`, I can not get the parameter later in that file by doing `$_GET['group_id'];`

In img_upload.php I am taking this other variable and inserting it into a database. So it would be really cool if I can get that variable in such a way I can get it into a php variable (I tried to be as clear as possible in this last line).
I would also add what I get in Chrome Developer Tool:

```
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundarydOdbB5IQ8RbA8CRR
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file[]"; filename="photo-5.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundarydOdbB5IQ8RbA8CRR--
```

That's what makes me think the problem is in the data sending script

Comment: Both methods should work. Show us the exact code of what you tried, please. Did you wait for DOMready before getting the `group_id` from the hidden input?

Comment: Since it's doing what it is supposed to do, I thought that's all I needed. What you see is pretty much what I have in the file. That said... No, I didn't wait for the DOMready. I'm going to work on that now!

Answer (score 1):

When you click 'submit' all input fields will be submitted to the server using a HTTP POST.

On the server you can interpret the request with something like (java)

```
request.getAttribute('uploaded_file');
```

In PHP this would be something like:

```
$myFile = $_REQUEST['uploaded_file'];
```

See [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php).

Edit: your input tag is invalid (remove the "/"):

```
<input type="hidden" id="group_id" name="group_id" value="2">
```

Edit2:

Add the following (as a test):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var el = document.getElementById('send_img');

el.addEventListener('submit', function(){
alert(document.getElementById("group_id").value);
return true;
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: That's correct, but I need to get the variable into php so it can be easily inserted in a database. (I'm adding that detail)

Comment: I have that part. I just need to get the variable group_id. Thanks for taking the time to help me!!!

Comment: That would be $myGroupId = $_REQUEST['group_id']; But i don't really have experience with PHP.

Comment: As I added above, the problem is not in the receiving file but in the sending one, where the javascript part is. You can see that the parameter group_id is not passed.

Comment: Edited me answer. An valid input tag is like <input>, not <input/>

Comment: Is the line var group_id = document.getElementById("group_id").value;
in the function Handlechange correct?

Comment: You are using 'multipart/form-data' (for sending files). It can be that this does not accept other form data. As a test, change to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't make any diference. Thank you very much for your patience. In the end I am going to get that variable through the referrer!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21612/discussion-between-asgoth-and-cbarg)